# Does sound quality increase if you play a video in High Definition?

Tags: sound, video, sound-quality

I have a friend who always tells me to listen to his sound videos in HD, because, he claims, the sound quality will go up if you watch the video in HD.

I've listened to the same video's in both HD and non-HD, and can't tell any difference in sound quality. His videos are posted on Facebook specifically, but I'm interested if this is true in any video.

Comment: sorry meed96, this is off topic here

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on where else I should put it? This site looked like the most relevant.

Comment: No sorry. This is a sound design site. I think you did get a good answer btw.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why this is off topic exactly, I read through the help center briefly, but don't see why this question isn't relevant, could you explain so I don't make the same mistake twice?

Comment: we are actually discussing about a new help center text, so i understand your question. it's not very clear at the moment. this is a sound design website, sound design is not a technical profession, it's an art form. your question is a 'end user' question and  is not relevant to our field of work. have a look around at the question and google on sound design. good luck

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the creator of a video can choose any combination of video-quality and audio-quality.

In practice, persons who know what they are doing, and also the automatic engines of YouTube (facebook should be similar) that create different quality versions of the same video, have profiles, where the quality of video and audio is linked.

So yes, higher quality video comes with higher quality audio on YouTube:
360p videos have 96 kbps audiotracks, while 720p videos habve 192 kbps audiotracks.

192 kbps is way better than 96 kbps. I don't have a 1080p-video here to check, but I remember that audio-quality reaches its maximum at 192 kbps. So 1080p-videos will not sound better than 720p-videos. For me, the sweet spot is 720p.